# DialogFragment: how to prevent saving state?

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have several classes extending DialogFragment to show popups. The model class that's used to show popup data comes from a library that I can't change.

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment {
   private List<MyModel> modelData;
 ...
}
```

Now, with the DialogFragment shown, if I hit the home button, I get a crash

> 06-09 17:21:04.265: E/AndroidRuntime(31470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value .....

The obvious fix for this is to change my MyModel class to implement Parcelable. I tried it with a similar case and it works but unfortunately all of my model classes that are used in DialogFragments are in a library and I cannot change to make them Parcelable and I don't want to do any wrapper classes.

I don't support orientation change and I don't have any usecase where the contents of the dialog need to be preserved. Is there any way I can simply ignore the state saving process so this crash can be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I just wanted to post the solution just in case anyone else runs into the same situation. I just had to override onPause like this

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}
```